# How to use ng-show and ng-hide in if condition using Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm  working  on  angularjs. I'm using  ng-show and ng-hide in my  html  table. The same way i need to show the value in  my  if condition also to show the coresponding values in my fusion chart.

Let me show you the chart by default i'm getting for the combination of **Count** and **Day**.[image]

Here is my  `html`  and `script`

index.html

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-hide="content == 'other'" ng-repeat='p in view_data'>
       <td><span>{{p.product}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.bucket}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.countOfAllocatedAccount}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.countOfCollectedAccount}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts}}</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-show="content == 'other'" ng-repeat='p in view_data'>
       <td><span>{{p.product}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.bucket}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.sumOfAllocatedAccount}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.sumOfCollectedAccount}}</span></td>
       <td><span>{{p.sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts}}</span></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

script.js

if `ng-hide="content == 'other'"` show this values

```
if(data[p].product==products[j])
     {
     var productWiseAllocation = {};
     productWiseAllocation.name=data[p].product;
     productWiseAllocation.series= data[p].bucket;
      productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].countOfAllocatedAccount;
      //productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].sumOfAllocatedAccount;
      productWiseAllocationarr.push( productWiseAllocation);
      var productWiseCollection ={};
      productWiseCollection.name=data[p].product;
       productWiseCollection.series=data[p].bucket;
        productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].countOfCollectedAccount;
        //productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].sumOfCollectedAccount;
        productWiseCollectionarr.push( productWiseCollection);
     }
```

For the combination of **Amount** and **Day** i.e,[image]

if `ng-show="content == 'other'"` I need to  show this values in my  fusion chart.

```
else{
      var productWiseAllocation = {};
     productWiseAllocation.name=data[p].product;
     productWiseAllocation.series= data[p].bucket;
      productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].sumOfAllocatedAccount;
      //productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].sumOfAllocatedAccount;
      productWiseAllocationarr.push( productWiseAllocation);
      var productWiseCollection ={};
      productWiseCollection.name=data[p].product;
       productWiseCollection.series=data[p].bucket;
        productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].sumOfCollectedAccount;
        //productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].sumOfCollectedAccount;
        productWiseCollectionarr.push( productWiseCollection);

     }
```

Can anyone help me from  this ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please ask in detail.

Comment: You can directly use `$scope.content` in your script.js .

Comment: @Sai  but how ? I have already  tried  the way  you  said.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of $scope.content, to see whether it ever is 'other'? As @Sai brought up - there isn't any reference to $scope.content in your script.js - where is it?